# $result is showing true every time

Tags: php, pdo

i just started learning PDO...

```
 function authenticate($username,$password)
 {
    $result=$this->con->query("select * from user where UserName='".$username."' AND Password='".$password."'");
    var_dump($result->rowCount()); //return null
    if($result)
        echo "hey going great";
    else
        echo "Hey are you gone mad?";
}
```

i am calling above function with **username** and **password**... but it's returning **hey going great** part every time if i will pass wrong username and password also...

i tried with **$result->rowCount()** but it's also returning null value...

Can you suggest me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. The query executes OK (hence why the `$result` var is true).

Comment: I *strongly* recommend reading about [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection)

Comment: What you could check for is if there is 1 (or more?) rows, then run the `Hey going great`.

Comment: @BeatAlex i tried to check that by $result->rowCount() but it's also return nothing in both the case (true data & false data).. how do i check it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try it as:

```
$result=$this->con->query("select * from user where UserName='".$username."' AND Password='".$password."'");
    var_dump($result->rowCount()); //return null
    $num_row=$result->rowCount();
    if($num_row > 0)
        echo "hey going great";
    else
        echo "Hey are you gone mad?";
```

Comment: SQL injection is a thing to avoid

Answer (score 2):

You are doing almost everything wrong.

First and foremost, the only reason for using PDO is using placeholders in the query.
You shouldn't also check the query result right in the function. So, make it

```
function authenticate($username,$password)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE UserName=? AND Password=?";
    $stm = $this->con->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute([$username,$password]);
    return $stm->fetch();
}
```

and then call

```
if($userdata = $user->authenticate($username,$password))
    echo "hey going great";
else
    echo "Hey are you gone mad?";
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$this->con` is an instance of `PDO`:

- `PDO->query()` only returns `false` on [failure](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php).
- `$result` will be an instance of [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php), which always evaluates to `true`
- [`PDOStatement->rowCount()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object.

  > If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a **SELECT** statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour **is not guaranteed** for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.

**Edit**: By the way, your application would be more safe, if you use [`PDO->prepare()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) (& bound parameters) instead of `PDO->query()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($result->rowCount()>0){
        echo "hey going great";
    }else{
        echo "Hey are you gone mad?";
}
```

Comment: it will return number of row not string

Comment: !='' And !=NULL are same. arent they?

Comment: here in select statement no rows are afected yes?? then?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($result)
```

This will always check for if the variable has any info. When ever you run a query and store in this var , it will store number of rows returned . Even if it is wrong , it will return a neg value which sets the variable.

Basically your **if** is just checking if the variable exists , it does exist in both cases.